# Python script in LabVIEW outputs "More?" to stdout

Tags: python, windows, cmd, labview

The following screenshot shows the LabVIEW block diagram and output.

[image: Screen shot of LabVIEW block diagram and front panel]

Here is the output text.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\sesa351813\Desktop\ajay\python>More?
```

Comment: You have a bracket somewhere. It's saying more commands before I execute it. You can see this when typing at command prompt, type `(dir` then enter. To finish use a closing bracket - `)`.

Comment: I don't know enough about LabVIEW to say why it's using cmd.exe to run a Python script, or why, given the latter, it isn't using "/c" to run a single command. Maybe that's just how you've set up the block diagram. Anyway, given you're scripting an interactive cmd prompt, each command line has to end with CRLF, else cmd will print "More?" until it reads CRLF on stdin.

Comment: i didnt understand, what is CRLF. do you mean like do i have to use CRLF literally? or is it an abbr??

Answer (score 4):

To use System Exec.vi you should pass what you are trying to execute to the 'command line' connector. Running as if from the command shell would require you to preface your command with '`cmd /c`'. To get a directory listing your could use:

[image: System Exec.vi]

In your case if you pass the string '`cmd /c python hello.py`' then this should execute correctly.

[image: System Exec.vi running python script]

Answer (score 2):

Execute `python` **directly** and don't go through the Windows command line. Replace `c:\full\path\to\python` with wherever it's installed on your system.

### Block Diagram

[image]

### Output

[image]

Comment: whats import this?, is it where i put my scripts name in?

Comment: No, it was just an example. python can execute a script given on the command line with the `-c` option, and the text that follows in the next argument, `"import this"`, is about the shortest built-in script you can execute. In your situation, you want to drop the `-c` option and specify the path to your python script instead.